# how to replace class name dynamically in javascript

Tags: javascript

I want to change a class dynamically and append a counter to the end of it. I wrote this code but it is treated like strings.

This is the code:

```
var divClass = document.getElementById('div2');
var i = 1;
setInterval(function () {
  divClass.className=divClass.className.replace('color','color'+ i);
  i++;
},5000);
```

how can i fix this issue?

Comment: 1) What is treated as a string? 2) What is the end state you would like your class name to look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the issue is that after the first loop the class name will be `color1` and your replacing only the "color" part so you end up with `color12` You could just set className since that overrides the previous one

```
divClass.className = 'color'+ i;
```

if you had classes before you can store them and them first so you don't override them : `var classes = divClass.className;`
and when you set them `divClass.className = classes + ', color'+ i;`

Answer (score 1):

You could use the `classList` feature that is in JavaScript like this:

```
var divClass = document.getElementById('div2');
var i = 1;
setInterval(function () {
    divClass.classList.remove('color' + (i - 1));
    divClass.classList.add('color' + i++);
}, 5000);
```

Your numbers are more than likely getting treated as a string because you are concatenating with a string. By placing items within parentheses, they will be executed as numbers (because anything in parentheses get run first) then concatenated as a string.

Answer (score 0):

Use instead:

```
element.className = 'other const clases' + 'color'+ i;
```

You have to change full string of class or change it in 2 steps with for example regex and then assign it again.